Solving the system $a^x=(x+y+z)^y$, $a^y=(x+y+z)^z$, $a^z=(x+y+z)^x$, for $x$, $y$, $z$
Given system of equations:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a ^ x = (x + y + z)^y \\ 
a ^ y = (x + y + z) ^ z \\ 
a ^ z = (x + y + z) ^ x
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
find the values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ where $a > 0$ and $a\neq1$.
My attempt:
I was solving the above problem using law of indices (I have not studied logarithms yet). I could show that $x=y=z= \frac{a}{3}$, though I need a formal solution. Also, how can I show that if $a$ is an integral multiple of $6$ then $x=y=z=\pm\frac{a}{3}$.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

If you include your solution for the fact $x = y = z = a/3$ then we might verify whether it is formal or not

There's a strange catch to your second part: The meaning of $A^B$ when $A$ is any real number and $B$ is any integer (except when $A=0$ and $B \leq 0$) and the meaning of $A^B$ when $A$ is any positive real number and $B$ is any real number are two different things. Even using complex numbers, there's no simple definition that covers both. So giving both as answers means we're finding solutions to the equations with one meaning plus solutions to the equations with another meaning. Usually we would say or imply from the domain which meaning it is from the start.

multiply all lines together and use that power functions are strictly increasing (you need also to address the special case $x+y+z=0$)

If you multiply all equations together you have $a^s=s^s$ where $s=x+y+z$. Isn't the solution of that $a=s$? In other words, $x+y+z=a$. But if you check the solution $(x,y,z)=(1,-1,a)$  it will only apply if $a\in{-1,1}$. So it seems like that general solution will only be valid for some $a$.

$$a^{x+y}=(x+y+z)^{y+z}\\a^{y+z}=(x+y+z)^{z+x}$$
We also had $a^{z+x}=(x+y+z)^{x+y}$, so
$$\frac{x+y}{z+x}=\frac{z+y}{x+y}=\frac{x+z}{y+z}$$
Solving them returns:-
$$(x+y)^3=(y+z)^3=(z+x)^3$$
Which, solving for real $x,y,z$ is only possible when $x=y=z$.So
$$a^z={(3z)^{z}} \\\implies (3z)=(a)\text{(odd z)},±(a)\text{(even z)}$$
This would help you prove both of your questions. For $a=6k$, $z$ will be even, so it must return two values.

But if $z = -\frac{a}{3}$ then $x + y + z < 0$ since $a > 0$, which contradicts with the first of your statements

@RupertRybka my first statement is wrong. I'll edit it out. (x+y+z)<0 if both powers are even on LHS and RHS
